# How to limit search results while using foreach and while loops

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

The following code works well, but I couldn't find a way to limit the number of results. Any ideas please?

```
    $q = "some keywords for search"; // always escape
    $keys = explode( " ",$q );
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE para LIKE '%$q%' ";

    foreach($keys as $k)
    {
        $query .= " OR para LIKE '%$k%'";
    }

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
       if ($row != 0) { 
       $title = $row['title'];
    }
    }
```

Any help while be appreciated.

Note: the $q holds the search keywords, and then the code explode it, and search for the keywords in 2 steps:
1- as one sentence using ($q as it is).
2- it searches for each keyword as an array after exploding the $q (here is the part that the "foreach" does).
After that the code loops using "while" to find all results match the search request.

Comment: `$query .= " OR para LIKE '%$k%' LIMIT x_number";` that's where it goes, not in the first part. You're also missing a closing brace.

Comment: Should I delete that ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, you are right, when I use "limit" at this point, the code works well since it finds the keywords in the database, but if it didn't find any of them, I get the following error: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in the line of fetch_assoc()

Comment: I corrected the code, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes I saw that, it's great. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LIMIT after completing your query.

Also, if you want to get results sorted by some fields in your table, you could also say " ORDER BY fieldname ASC|DESC"

As follows:

```
$q = "some keywords for search"; // always escape
$keys = explode( " ",$q );
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE para LIKE '%$q%' ";

foreach($keys as $k)
{
    $query .= " OR para LIKE '%$k%'";
}

$query .= " LIMIT 10"; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<    

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
   if ($row != 0) { 
   $title = $row['title'];
}
```

Comment: WOW, you did it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use LIMIT.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE para LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work because the query is divided to 3 parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of results in your MySQL query, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE para LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 5";
```

this will limit it to 5 results.  If you want 10, change it to 10